# Typescript dynamically assign a part of variable name

Tags: typescript

In the typescript, I have the following:

```js
information_1: any;
information_2: any;
information_3: any;

for(var datum in data){                    
    this.information_[datum] = data[datum]; //Of course this is not right.
}
```

In js, there is a way to dynamically assign a part of variable name. Is there something like that in typescript so that I can have `this.information_1` or `this.information_2` etc. based on the `var datum`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You certainly can, but you'll need to avoid the dot notation.

```js
[key:string]:any;
    
for(var datum in data){                    
    this['information_' + datum] = data[datum]; 
}
```

Comment: How to use this variable in attribute binding in angular template